# 'multiple' prop in Vuetify not working for file uploads

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify to create a form that includes the ability to upload files. I've made sure to include the 'multiple' prop to allow users to upload more than 1 file. However whenever I try to upload another file it just erases the already uploaded file, how can I make it so that it is added to the array of files:

```
data: () => ({
    files: []
}),
```

This is the code for the file upload:

```
    <v-flex>
    <v-file-input
        v-model="files"
        color="deep-purple accent-4"
        counter
        label="File input"
        multiple="true"
        placeholder="Select file(s)"
        prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
        outlined
    >
        <template v-slot:selection="{ index, text }">
        <v-chip
            color="deep-purple accent-4"
            dark
            label
            small
        >
            {{ text }}
        </v-chip>
        </template>
    </v-file-input>
    </v-flex>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the dialog window of files explorer appears press `ctrl` key and choose multiple files , the `multiple` prop means this way not as you're doing by choosing a file and trying to add others by opening new dialog window.

Comment: Wow it is truly astonishing that the vuetify docs do not explain this, thank you